# What is the mathematical term for this polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, terminology, polyhedra

Does anyone know a specific name for the heptacube X33b in the link below? Since it has a very symmetric shape, I thought it might have a name for it.

http://www.recmath.com/PolyPages/PolyPages/Heptacubes/Pictures/Q5_4.png

Google image search with the Japanese term 六脚ブロック result in many of these polyhedron. But that is a name of the concrete structure product. I want to know the mathematical term for it.
https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E5%85%AD%E8%84%9A%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF&tbm=isch

I was playing with baby floor mats (joint mat) last weekend and came up with this shape. That is why I am curious.
[image: model made by joint mat]

Comment: It's a Rubik's cube with the edge and corner pieces removed.

Comment: I found "heptocubic"(https://1320frequencyshift.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/heptocubico.jpg) which is a part of (http://www.jainmathemagics.com/Workbook3DimGeometry/). See also (https://circlesandtrianglesblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/06/three-dimensional-tessellation/). Another reference: Dali's cross with the base cube removed (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycube#Octacubes_and_hypercube_unfoldings)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you. All the references are interesting!

Comment: @terrace Yes we can say it that way too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest (named) polyhedron I know of is the [tetrahemihexacron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahemihexahedron#Tetrahemihexacron), what a mouthful!

Here is the image from the Wikipedia page:

[image: Tetrahemihexacron]

Polyhedra can get pretty weird, so not everyone agrees that this thing is a proper polyhedron, because it has vertices at infinity (those rectangular prisms continue on forever).

So really, you would need to take the tetrahemihexacron, and cut off portions of those "bars" until they had finite length (I'm not sure there's a name for this polyhedron operation, since it normally returns a combinatorially equivalent polytope; i.e., does nothing interesting).

I think that those "bars" each extend to a single vertex at infinity, so that clipping off the excess counts as truncation. If true, it's possible that you have a *truncated tetrahemihexacron*. But it's probably more correct to say that your polyhedron matches *models* of a tetrahemihexacron.

Comment: Maybe, to highlight the fact that all side lengths are equal, we can call it a "regular truncated tetrahemihexacron"?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee That's not a bad idea, although I'm really reconsidering this answer -- I think OP's polyhedron and this one are rather different beasts, even though they look (very) similar, so it seems kind of dishonest to suggest this term. I don't know though...

Comment: Thank you for the information! Although it is not perfect match to my question, it seems your information is the closest, as you have mentioned.